# Regex: match parts of the same string but excluding a specific part

Tags: r, regex

I have this string `"ACC_OR.A5J1.01A"`. Now I want to match everything except for `01`.
Until now I have used the pattern`.*\\.` which matches everything until 01A.   Now I want to also match the last character `"A"`( which can be any character actually). Finally, I want to have everything matched except `01` ( which can also be any 2 digits). 
My question is is there a way to capture everything and exclude the 2 digits `01`?

EDIT: I'm using this in `R`, my idea was to capture those parts so I can use sub() function and replace the matched parts with `""`. What I want finally, is to get the 2 digits.

Comment: Will it be 2 separate matches, `ACC_OR.A5J1.` and `A`

Comment: No, I would like to match it with a single expression. Is it possible to ignore 01 and just match ACC_OR.A5J1. and A? I'm relatively new to regex. For more information im using this in R. Where I have a list of strings similar like the one before mentioned and I want to generate a new list, which only contains the the two digits. Using the sub() function i want to replace the matched string and replace it with nothing, so in the end i only have the 2 digits.

Comment: Only if you replace. You can't match non-adjoining pieces of a string within one match operation.

Comment: why do you need a regular expression? This can be done by simple string manipulations, just extract all characters except the two you wish to ignore

Comment: like I said I am new to all this, can you explain how you would do this, with what function? For now I have only been trying using regex, I am able to create my wanted list, but in 2 steps using regex. If there was a way to do it in one go, please fill me in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YibioaWang Please add the `r` tag to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be better solved without regex. If all you need is to exclude second-to-last 2 characters from the string, you could do it via `string.substr()` like this:

```js
let str = "ACC_OR.A5J1.01A";
console.log( str.substr(0, str.length - 3) +  str.substr(-1) );
```

Answer (score 0):

To match what is before and after the 2 digits you could use 2 capturing groups.

As there are no spaces (`.*` will also match spaces), you might use `\S` to match a non whitespace char.

```
(\S+\.)\d{2}(\S)
```

- `(\S+\.)` Capture group 1, match 1+ non whitespace chars until the last dot
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `(\S)` Capture group 2, match a non whitespace char

Then you could use the 2 groups separately.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s7cdJS/1)

---

Or you could make use of `\K` to match the digits and replace with an emtpy string

```
\S+\.\K\d{2}(?=\S)
```

- `\S+\.` match 1+ non whitespace chars until the last dot
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `\d{2}` Match 2 digits
- `(?=\S)` Assert what is on the right is a non whitspace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FINWK/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/DZD4XH)

For example

```
sub("\\S+\\.\\K\\d{2}(?=\\S)", "", "ACC_OR.A5J1.01A", perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "ACC_OR.A5J1.A"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to extract the two characters before the last character. You can read more about the [`substr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/substr)

```
x<- "ACC_OR.A5J1.01A"
cat(substr(x, nchar(x)-2, nchar(x)-1))
```

Output

```
01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this does exactly what i need